# Any way to change "From" Text in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, send-email

Good morning all,

I have a requirement which needed me to build a form and an email notifcations workflow based on certain parameters.  The team wants the emails' sender to read "CASE System Request".  the problem is, we don't have an existing mailbox with that name.  Since I'm using Power Automate, I haven't found a way to do that.  I can send the emails with the "From" field reading either my name (v2), or Microsoft PowerApps (v3).  Is there any option for me to modify the "From" text?  These aren't emails that anyone will be replying to.

Thank you!

Comment: "From" should be a valid email address.

Answer (score 0):

You could use send an email(V2) action ,click “show advanced option”
[image]
Click ‘From (Send as)’, enter email address. So that you can set email sender.
[image]